# Moving the first char in a string to the send of the string using a method. C#

Tags: c#

I know there are a lot of similar questions asked, and I've looked over those, but I still can't figure out my solution.
I'm trying to write a method that takes the first character of an inputted string and moves it to the back, then I can add additional characters if needed.
Basically if the input is **Hello** the output would be **elloH** + "whatever." I hope that makes sense.
As proof that I'm just not being lazy, here is  the rest of the source code for the other parts of what I am working on. It all works, I just don't know where to begin with the last part.
Thanks for looking and thanks for the help!

```
    private string CaseSwap(string str)//method for swaping cases
    {

        string result = ""; //create blank var
        foreach (var c in str) 
            if (char.IsUpper(c)) //find uppers
                result += char.ToLower(c); //change to lower
            else
                result += char.ToUpper(c); //all other lowers changed to upper
        str = result; //assign var to str

        return str; //return string to method
    }

    private string Reverse(string str)//method for reversing string
    {
        char[] revArray = str.ToCharArray(); //copy into an array
        Array.Reverse(revArray); //reverse the array
        return new string(revArray); //return the new string

    }

    private string Latin(string str)//method for latin
    {

      
    }
}
```

}

Comment: And by '+ whatever' I presume you're writing a pig-latin translation? It's a lot less simple than you think :P

Comment: @Aaron, your last update to the question won't help others. Please revert your question to its actual problem statement. If any of the below answer helped to solve your problem, then kindly accept it by green tick.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to update your question

Answer (score 0):

Why not just take the 1st char and combine it with the rest of the string? E.g.

```
Hello
^^  ^
||  |
|Substring(1) - rest of the string (substring starting from 1)
|  
value[0]      - first character
```

**Code:**

```
public static string Rotate(string value) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) 
  ? value
  : $"{value.Substring(1)}{value[0]}";
```

Generalized implementation for arbitrary rotation (either positive or negative):

```
public static string Rotate(string value, int count = 1) {
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    return value;

  return string.Concat(Enumerable
    .Range(0, value.Length)
    .Select(i => value[(i + count % value.Length + value.Length) % value.Length]));
}
```

You can simplify your current implementation with a help of *Linq*

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static string CaseSwap(string value) =>
  string.Concat(value.Select(c => char.IsUpper(c) 
    ? char.ToLower(c) 
    : char.ToUpper(c)));

private static string Reverse(string value) =>
  string.Concat(value.Reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move first character to the end of string, then you can try below

```
public string MoveFirstCharToEnd(string str, string whateverStr="")
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
      return str;

   string result = str.Substring(1) + str[0] + whateverStr;
   return result;
}
```

**Note:** I added `whateverStr` as an optional parameter, so that it can support only moving first character to the end and also it supports concatenating extra string to the result.

---

[`String.Substring(Int32):`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32))

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a
> specified character position and continues to the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had been looking all over, trying all sorts of solutions with no success. This was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the first character of a string with the [String.Substring(int startPosition, int length) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0) . With this method you can also get the rest of your text starting from position 1 (skip the first character). When you have these 2 pieces, you can concat them.

*Don't forget to check for empty strings, this can be done with the [String.IsNullOrEmpty(string text) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0)*.

```
public static string RemoveAndConcatFirstChar(string text){
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return "";

    return text.Substring(1) + text.Substring(0,1);
}
```

Comment: You can drop `text.Length - 1` from `text.Substring(1, text.Length - 1)` and have `text.Substring(1)`.

Comment: Please note, that when method is `public` you should validate input argument(s): what if `text` is `null`? Empty - `""`

Comment: There's no need in `this` in the method, so you can declare it as `static`

Answer (score 0):

Appending multiple characters to a string is inefficient due to the number of string objects allocated, which is not just memory intensive it's also slow. There's a reason we have `StringBuilder` and other such options available to us, like working with `char[]`s.

Here's a fairly quick method that for rotating a string left one character (moving the first character to the end):

```
string RotateLeft(string source)
{
    var chars = source.ToCharArray();
    var initial = chars[0];
    Array.Copy(chars, 1, chars, 0, chars.Length - 1);
    chars[^1] = initial;
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Sadly we can't do that in-place in the string itself since they're immutable, so there's no avoiding the temporary array and string construction at the end.

---

Based on the fact that you called the method `Latin(...)` and the bit of the question where you said: "Basically if the input is Hello the output would be elloH + "whatever."... I'm assuming that you're writing a Pig Latin translation. If that's the case, you're going to need a bit more.

Pig Latin is a slightly tricky problem because it's based on the sound of the word, not the letters. For example, `onto` becomes `ontohay` (or variants thereof) while `one` becomes `unway` because the word is pronounced the same as `won` (with a `u` to capture the vowel pronunciation correctly). Phonetic operations on English is quite annoying because of all the variations with silent and implied initial letters. And don't even get me started on pseudo-vowels like `y`.

Special cases aside, the most common rules of Pig Latin translation code appear to be as follows:

1. Words starting with a single consonant followed by a vowel: move the consonant to the end and append `ay`.
2. Words starting with a pair of consonants followed by a vowel: move the consonant pair to the end and append `ay`.
3. Words that start with a vowel: append `hay`, `yay`, `tay`, etc.

That third one is a bit difficult since choosing the right suffix is a matter of what makes the result easiest to say... which code can't really decide all that easily. Just pick one and go with that.

Of course there are plenty of words that don't fit those rules. Anything starting with a consonant triplet for example (`Christmas` being the first that came to mind, followed shortly by `strip`... and others). Pseudo-vowels like `y` mess things up (`cry` for instance). And of course the ever-present problem of correctly representing the initial vowel sounds when you've stripped context: `won` is converted to `un-way` vocally, so rendering it as `on-way` in text is a little bit wrong. Same with `word`, whose Pig Latin version is pronounced `erd-way`.

For a simple first pass though... just follow the rules, treating `y` as a consonant if it's the first letter and as a vowel in the second or third spots.

And since this is so often a homework problem, I'm going to stop here and let you play with it for a bit. Just in case :P

(Oh, and don't forget to preserve the case of your first character just in case you're working on a capitalized word. `Latin` should become `Atinlay`, not `atinLay`. Just saying.)